# How to make functions.httpsCallable("findItems").call(["lat": userLocation?.latitude, "long": userLocation?.longitude]) request?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

There is not enough documents about firebase functions.httpsCallable("findItems").call() usage. I have deployed functions on firebase:

```
exports.findItems = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
// Grab the long parameter.
functions.logger.log(data.long, typeof data.long);
functions.logger.log(data.lat, typeof data.lat);
const long = parseFloat(data.long);
const lat = parseFloat(data.lat);
functions.logger.log(long, typeof long);
functions.logger.log(lat, typeof lat);
    //...
}
```

I make a request in swift using functions.httpsCallable("findItems").call() but the log always says there is no correct parameters:
[image: new error]

```
functions.httpsCallable("findItems").call(["lat": userLocation?.latitude, "long": userLocation?.longitude]) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                    let message = error.localizedDescription
                    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                }
                // ...
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print(result?.data)
            do{
                let json =  try JSONDecoder().decode([ItemLocation].self, from:result?.data as! Data)
                print(json)
            }catch{

            }
            
            
            
//            if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?

            
            //(result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
            //self.resultField.text = text
        }
```

You can find the offcial documents from : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

-----Update---------

I have tried everything by debugging and the passed parameters are always undefined but I follow every step on the official doc.
I have made changes and use onCall but it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up HTTP functions with callable functions.  Your client code is trying to call a callable function, but your function itself is defined as an HTTP function.  This won't work at all.  You should review the documentation for callable function and use `functions.https.onCall` instead of `functions.https.onRequest` to define your function.  They are completely different APIs.

Comment: Hello, I have changed the deployed functions but it still can't get parameters? Any suggestion?